# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express - no option to create new DB - what I am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I *would like* to create a new database in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express using the Management  Studio, but there is no option for `New Database...` I searched online and all the tutorials show this option that I don't have. What step am I missing? The "Object Explorer" is blank.

Comment: A screenshot of what you're seeing in management studio would go a long way to help us try to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry I'm too new to add screenshots apparently. Like I said, the "Object Explorer" is blank. What do I have to do before creating a db? What are the steps from opening the Management Studio?

Comment: Did you remember to connect to the server first?

Comment: as Kev said: try connecting to `localhost\sqlexpress`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right clicking on the database folder and 'new database'?
[image]